# How to resolve can't find module error in react.js

Tags: reactjs

```
import { ColorModeContext, useMode } from "./theme";
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import Topbar from "./scenes/global/Topbar";
import Sidebar from "./scenes/global/Sidebar";

function App() {
  const [theme, colorMode] = useMode();
  return (
    <ColorModeContext.Provider value={colorMode}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline/>
        <div className="app">
          <main className="content">
            <Topbar/>
            <Sidebar/>           
          </main>
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ColorModeContext.Provider>
  );
}
export default App;
```

- List item
  npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN While resolving: react-slidedown@2.4.7

npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0

npm WARN node_modules/react

npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project

npm WARN   16 more (@emotion/react, @emotion/styled, ...)

npm WARN

npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer react@"^16.3.0 || 17" from react-slidedown@2.4.7

npm WARN node_modules/react-pro-sidebar/node_modules/react-slidedown

npm WARN   react-slidedown@"^2.4.5" from react-pro-sidebar@0.7.1

npm WARN   node_modules/react-pro-sidebar

npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2

npm WARN node_modules/react

npm WARN   peer react@"^16.3.0 || 17" from react-slidedown@2.4.7

npm WARN   node_modules/react-pro-sidebar/node_modules/react-slidedown

npm WARN     react-slidedown@"^2.4.5" from react-pro-sidebar@0.7.1

npm WARN     node_modules/react-pro-sidebar

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN While resolving: react-slidedown@2.4.7

npm WARN Found: react-dom@18.2.0

npm WARN node_modules/react-dom

npm WARN   react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the r

oot project
npm WARN   6 more (@mui/base, @mui/material, @testing-library/react,

...)
npm WARN

npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@"^16.3.0 || 17" from react-slidedown@2.4.7

npm WARN node_modules/react-pro-sidebar/node_modules/react-slidedown

npm WARN   react-slidedown@"^2.4.5" from react-pro-sidebar@0.7.1

npm WARN   node_modules/react-pro-sidebar

npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react-dom@17.0.2

npm WARN node_modules/react-dom

npm WARN   peer react-dom@"^16.3.0 || 17" from react-slidedown@2.4.7

npm WARN   node_modules/react-pro-sidebar/node_modules/react-slidedown

npm WARN     react-slidedown@"^2.4.5" from react-pro-sidebar@0.7.1

npm WARN     node_modules/react-pro-sidebar

---

Comment: May be your TopBar and SideBAr is not correct.

Comment: Or Might you have missed any dependency?

Comment: Show your App.js file please

Comment: I think you badly exported that modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.src/` part from the paths for those 2 imports

```
import Topbar from "./scenes/global/Topbar"
import Sidebar from "./scenes/global/Sidear"
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/5UCJNaZryXC8

Comment: Have you installed your dependencies?

Comment: If not, you need to run `npm install` from the root directory

Comment: Also, please add the code instead of screenshots as it makes it easier for everyone to see your code.

Answer (score 0):

you should navigate to the root directory of your react project, then run `npm install` command to install all modules, and run `npm run start` to start your react app